# Simplest way of including ghostscript in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, latex, ghostscript, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a very simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that reads

```
  compile_pdf:
    image: listx/texlive:2017
    script:
      - pdflatex mydocument
      - biber mydocument
      - pdflatex mydocument
      - pdflatex mydocument
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - mydocument.pdf
    expire_in: 1d
```

that compiles a file `mydocument.tex` with the CI for each commit. It's been working fine until the point I started using `.eps` figures. These are converted to `.pdf` on my local machine fine, but not on the CI. I'm fairly sure this is due to it missing an installation of ghostscript.

What's the easiest way to include ghostscript in my job? I'd like to keep the setup to the bare minimum (e.g. avoid using Docker).

Comment: Maybe you could try something like https://framagit.org/spalax/pdfautonup/commit/56e041f8254dc257af7c6a85599682909b5ea128 ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @samcarterisattopanswers.xyz, but that doesn't seem to work for me... but maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I solved it by scavenging for the right Docker images (texlive+ghostscript).

[aergus/latex](https://hub.docker.com/r/aergus/latex) did the trick for me.